# How to get current Users between Sign In and Sign Out using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to implement a C# winforms report system where it displays the current users in the building upon clicking the generate button

The users table in the database have a signIn and SignOut column.

How would you query the database to get current users upon button click depending on these two columns? I tried using the NOW() attribute in the query but it wont work if someone signs out

```
SELECT SignID, SignIn, SignOut, UserID Now() AS PerDate 
FROM dbo.SignInOut
```

Comment: Is the signout field null until they sign out? also are there multiple lines per user (e.g. there sign in and out information from yesterday)

Comment: signout field is null and no multiple lines, it starts fresh every day at midnight

Comment: then simple just look for user id's where signout is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter on the `SignIn` and `SignOut` dates (assuming they both are of date data type):

```
SELECT SignID, SignIn, SignOut, UserID
FROM dbo.SignInOut
WHERE SignIn < GetDate()
  AND SignOut IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

As i said in the comments just limit it where SignOut IS NULL

```
SELECT UserID
FROM SignInOut
WHERE SignOut IS NULL
```